# Which Travis CI "language" setting should be used to just instantiate a Docker container?

Tags: docker, travis-ci

My project's build is invoked through a Docker image which is self-contained and does not require any other tools to be provided by the Travis environment.

However, all the documented "language" options at https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/ cause tools that I don't need to be installed.

What is the simplest possible "language" setting which ensures that Docker can be used?

Comment: Could people downvoting please address the reason so I could either fix the question, nor learn and not make the same mistake again?

Comment: ...ahh -- so you're having Travis instantiate a separate container which contains all your development tools, so you don't need the Travis CI system to have any particular tools itself?

Comment: Under "Just a docker" I meant that whatever I need is inside and I don't need anything else, just the docker container I have. I tried to rephrase the question for the future if somebody will have different problem, will not be confused by my bad English :-)

Comment: Thank you for that clarification -- if you don't mind, I'll try to reword a little further myself. :)

Comment: Yes, i don't need anything from Travis CI except the docker. We have outlier setup and usually no generic service would have support for these tools, so we had to dokerize everything we need.

Comment: Feel free to do so, as your English is much better than mine :) And thank you very much again.

Comment: NP. I extended the answer a little bit  to contain information you presumably already know (since you have docker working for you), but which may be useful to others trying to figure out how to use it from Travis CI. If I got any of those details wrong, feel free to propose an edit.

Comment: Yes, it's so much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that you have Docker tools available, you can (per the documentation at https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/) use:

```
sudo: required

services:
 - docker
```

This does not depend on a `language` setting. Thus, one can use in conjunction the ([presently undocumented](https://github.com/travis-ci/docs-travis-ci-com/issues/910) but supported) simplest available language setting, called `generic`.

As you can see in [`lib/travis/yaml/nodes/language.rb`](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-yaml/blob/da2c9860299fa63769ac1ee120abeb9e83615555/lib/travis/yaml/nodes/language.rb), this `generic` language is also available under the names `bash`, `sh`, `shell`, and `minimal`.

Comment: I would say the sudo/service might be redundant in some cases, but it will not hurt